# Redirect Cloud foundry streaming logs to a Virtual Machine

Tags: logging, cloud-foundry, syslog, application-monitoring

I have a distributed cloud foundry setup on Azure.

To access the application logs I have to use `cf logs <app-name>`.
Also I am able to see all cloud foundry logs using firehose plugin.

But all these logs are streaming logs.

Is there a way to redirect and store these logs to a different virtual machine outside cloud foundry setup?

I want to be able to access the logs later on to analyse in case something crashes or any error occurs.

So basically I want to store the cloud foundry streaming logs locally on a particular virtual machine. I don't want to use third party log management service.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a user provided service that redirects all logs of an application to a syslog server.  This setting is applied per application.

```
cf cups my-application-logger -l syslog://remote-machine-logger
cf bs my-application my-application-logger
```

Syslog in your 'remote-machine-logger' vm will have your application logs.

Comment: My use case: I want to push the cloud foundry streaming logs to a central location (s3 or blob storage). To debug any issue I want to be able to go to the s3 or blob storage location and do analysis on the logs at application level. Is there a way to do it from cloud foundry?

Comment: To use a central syslog you would create a vm and install something like rsyslog to store the logs.

Comment: @doit were you able to come up with a solution to send the firehose to s3?

Comment: There are existing 3rd party syslog providers like PaperTrail, Splunk, Loggly. They provide advanced analysis and persist the logs. Can you please see if they meet your requirements?